# Black screen when opening Cocos2dx activity

Tags: java, android, performance, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have an application that I built in Android Studio that has 5 modules that are games. 2 of them are games built using Cocos2dx. When either of the Cocos2dx games is selected in the app the screen goes black for a second as it loads up and then the game starts. Then when you exit the game the screen goes white for a second before it goes back to the main menu of the app. The time it goes black/blank varies from device to device. I think this is being caused by the large amounts of memory the cocos2dx uses. Is there any way of avoiding this? Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: is there any code? which version of cocos2d-x?

Comment: Its a massive project so hard to know what code to show. Its version 3.4

Comment: Make sure your textures are not bigger than 2048x2048. Can remove some part of images to see if something will show up?